# How to setup google apps account openId for Gerrit

Tags: openid, google-apps, gerrit, google-account

I am trying to setup `Gerrit` with `OpenID` as access control. I need my `google apps account` to be used as openID. I have tried a couple of ways to achieve this but so far not succesfull. This is what my `gerrit config` looks like:

```
[auth]
    type = OPENID
    allowedOpenID = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=mysite.com'
```

For the above configuration, I am getting a `Provider is not allowed` error while trying to login.

It works fine with normal `google` account, but not with the `google apps account` . I have already read many posts in `stackoverflow` and `gerrit` developer sites, but nothing have worked for me. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
The problem was using single quotes `'` around the url. Howerver now there is a new issue: Once I sign-in and come back to my site it says:
`The page you requested was not found, or you do not have permission to view this page`

The URL redirected `mysite.com/#SignInFailure,SIGN_IN,Provider+not+allowed` . Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching and reading the documentation I came across [this commit](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/d2ab0cda62799face3caa1973a57849d2f337f00). I tried it in Gerrit 2.7-rc1 and it worked.

Your gerrit config should contain the following:

```
[auth]
    type = OPENID
    trustedOpenID = https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=
    openIdDomain = @mysite.com
```

This permits me to log in using with any OpenID enabled email address in the domain mysite.com and prohibits others. Note that the '@' has to be there it doesn't work without it. ;-)

Additionally if you only want to allow Google as an OpenID provider you may want to set the following to skip the selection of OpenID providers:

```
[auth]
    type = OPENID_SSO
    openIdDomain = @mysite.com
    openIdSsoUrl = https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
```

[Documentation for Gerrit 2.6](https://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/config-gerrit.html) also contains this information.

Comment: Didn't work for me in Gerrit 2.9. Same error `OpenID auth request contains an unregistered domain`

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `canonicalWebUrl` property in your gerrit config?

Comment: Yes, I have. After authentication it do come back to my site: the problem is it says 'provider not allowed'. A 2011 post says its not supported in gerrit: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/repo-discuss/qhUfy70BODY . Not sure if its still the case.